# Apache servicemix OSGi bundle fails to import packages

Tags: java, osgi

I am not an experienced OSGi user yet and I get some problems consequently.

I am trying to use `org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hadoop-client` as an external `hadoop` provider because I don't want my bundle to contain all of those classes.

But when I run the set of bundles (my and `org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hadoop-client`) I get the following error:

> ERROR: Bundle org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hadoop-client [56] Error starting file:bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hadoop-client_2.8.1.1.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hadoop-client [56](R 56.0): missing requirement [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hadoop-client [56](R 56.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=corg.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hadoop-client [56](R 56.0): missing requiremom.google.inject)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hadoop-client [56ent [org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hadoop-client [56](R 56.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.inject)(ve](R 56.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.inject)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))])
>   rsion>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hadoop-client [56](R 56.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.inject)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111)
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1371)
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I understand that `org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hadoop-client` imports `com.google.inject` and expects that some other bundle exports it.

My own bundle imports `com.google.inject` as well and it works properly. The only difference is that my bundle uses version `3.0` and `hadoop` wants `4.0`.

Both of the `com.google.inject` `3.0` and `4.0` bundles are in the `osgi_container/bundles` folder.

I've even tried to force my bundle to `<export-package>` `com.google.inject` and it "worked". The error began to ask for another library. `</stupid attemtps>`

So I'm stuck at the point. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

The core of the exception above is this

```
(&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.inject)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
```

It means that the hadoop-client needs a bundle that exports the package com.google.inject in a version [3.0.0,4.0.0). This means all package versions from 3.0.0 until excluding 4.0.0 should be valid.

As mentioned in the comment by PanzOr google guice seems to export the package com.google.inject in a different version. The newest guice exports the version 1.4. So it seems the hadoop client bundle might be broken. As its import range uses the bundle version not the actual package version.

Btw. I gave up installing any big data project in OSGi. They all seem to have hughe dependency trees with a lot of non OSGi dependencies. So they are really hard to install.

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any other points beside that the bundle `com.google.inject.3.0` must be contained in bundles folder (because it is) :(

Comment: Btw, `com.google.inject` has `Bundle-Version: 3.0.0` but `Export-Package: ..
 ,com.google.inject;version="1.3"`

Comment: Oh .. thanks for spotting this. I expected the google inject bundle to export packages with the bundle version.  Seems they are actually doing semantic versioning. In this case I wonder if the import of hadoop-client are maybe broken.